# Studying a sequence of integrals, whose integrand is the $arctan$ function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

For $x \geq 0$ I've the following sequence of integral I'd like to study

$$
f(x)=\lim_{N\rightarrow+\infty}\int_{0}^{N} \arctan \left(2^{-(t-1)x}\right)dt
$$

To solve it I've tried the following, but I'm not sure I'm doing right...
I've applied the variable change

$$
u = \frac{N^2}{N-t} - N \Rightarrow t = N - \frac{N^2}{N+u} \Rightarrow dt = \frac{N^2}{(N+u)^2}du
$$

Then the original integral becomes

$$
f(x)=\lim_{N\rightarrow+\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{N^2}{(N+u)^2}\arctan \left(2^{-\left(N-1+\frac{N^2}{N+u}\right)x}\right)du
$$

Now I've tried, but probably I couldn't do it, to exchange the lim sign with the integral sign, because I thought I could apply the dominate convergence theorem, but I did end up with a divergent integral, which I don't think is correct, given that the integral can be bounded above by a convergent series.

How can I proceed from here? I don't know whether or not there's a closed form solution of the integral, but I'm more interested in seeing what it looks like after the limit operation.

Comment: Have you considered integration by parts?

Comment: For the original integral? I'm not sure that would be useful

Comment: For $t>1$, the function is asymptotic to $2^{-(t-1)x}$ and converges (the $\arctan$ linearizes).